# Install to the common templates folder with wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In the list of [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties) provided by Windows installer, I see a `TemplateFolder` which is the "*full path to the Template folder for the current user*". So I can use `TemplateFolder` as the Directory ID in wix to install user-specific templates.

However, I need to install to the *common* templates folder, i.e. the one referred to as `CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES` (also `FOLDERID_CommonTemplates`) in the windows API. Windows installer doesn't seem to provide a system folder property for this one.

How do I install files to the common templates folder with wix?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/msi/installation-context) tells us on the "TemplateFolder"-ID that it **depends on the installation context** whether it is "the full path of the Templates folder for all users" (per-machine) or "the full path of the Templates folder for the current user" (per-user).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer: It does include the essential parts.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks for mention that it does include the essential parts.
For me this works in the WiX environment as expected.

Comment: The documentation on the [TemplateFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372069(v=vs.85).aspx) property itself claims that the ALLUSERS property only has this effect on Windows 2000, but maybe I shouldn't have trusted that information.

Comment: @WimCoenen Correct, I've read that too and was somewhat irritated by it. I've added a comment there, as the documentation is definitely not correct.

Comment: @WimCoenen it took some time, but the documentation on the [TemplateFolder Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/templatefolder) is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining a `COMMONTEMPLATEFOLDER` like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id='TARGETDIR'>
  <Directory Id='COMMONTEMPLATEFOLDER' Name='Templates' />
</DirectoryRef>

<Property Id="COMMONTEMPLATEFOLDER">
   <RegistrySearch Id="searchCommonTemplateFolder"
      Root="HKLM"
      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
      Name="Common Templates"
  Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

This seems to work fine, but unfortunately it relies on [undocumented registry entries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx). I would still like to find a better way.